# How can I reach the entire moderator team at once, to let them know I'd like private advice from one or more?

Tags: support

This is a procedural question.

How can we reach all the moderators of the site at one time, especially if I want private advice.

The purpose would never be to take them away from the hard, extremely important work they do for us!

It would be to let all of them know I have a private question or issue, and if any or all had the time or interest, they could respond. It might be something that could be asked here on meta, but I wouldn't want the general public to know I asked it. More likely it would be something I would eventually ask on meta after getting moderator advice as to how to approach it.

I know if we flag a post it goes into a queue which all the mods have access to, but the kind of thing I might want to ask wouldn't be related to a specific post or person, so that doesn't feel right.

In the past, I've asked my questions to a specific mod by pinging him from the chat room, but I don't like to keep expecting something from that same person. He generally comes quickly when I ping, but that doesn't mean he'd be interested in my question.

I think I saw somewhere that, if they feel it's appropriate, a moderator can create a "private" chat room, which works like a regular chat room but can only be seen by other moderators on the same site, and nobody else. Is that true? Can that be used as a way to let them all see my question/issue, and let any or all of them weigh in only if they want or have time?  Would moderators do something like that?

I looked around the site and couldn't find an option to contact the team. I also looked around Meta:SE and ended up lost!

The Contact link at the bottom of each page goes directly to the Community Team Staff. What I might want to know would not need them, and it would be a rude waste of their time.

Is there a way to contact all the site moderators at one time? How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can't and you should not try.

To begin with, moderators are volunteers. Asking them all to meet you at the same time in a private chat room is not fair to you or them.

Whatever is so important that you think requires the attention off all the moderators you should use the link you already found https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/contact to contact SE staff.  They actually get paid to address complex issues.  If there really is a need to contact all the moderatore SE staff has ways of doing that.

**Edit**

Moderators are just users with a couple more tools, most of which are available to high rep users.  Most of the mods spend less time on this site then you do.  If there is a post that needs mod attention flag it and leave a comment, this is as private as anything can be on an SE sit.  See related meta post [An @Moderators ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126988/217279)

If is about something other than an existing post, then instead of asking one of our mods, you could post a question at one of the sites I listed below. If you want the post to be private, don't post it as you current account.  If you are tempted to use multiple accounts see [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/217279)

- [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)
- [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com)

Firstly/lastly? Before asking search [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) somebody has probably already asked your question there.

Comment: Thanks for your time James! It was never my intent to pull the awesome team away from the hard work they do! I re-wrote it to clarify what I really meant, which is just that when I need or want mod help, I'd like to let them know in case any would choose to help. It's so that I don't ping a specific one and bother him. That's what I actually meant. I definitely didn't express it properly! Please accept my sincere apology for that!! I also greatly apologize for if/how my edits affected this answer.

Comment: @Sue, the mods are not doing hard work for us, the spend less time here then you do.  They stop in once in a while and look for flags and address them if they feel like it.  They have real lives and real jobs, and doing mod tasks is just a hobby, just like everyone who posts here.  They have only slightly more powers that high rep user like you and I. About the only difference between a moderator and you or I, is that when they vote close or open, it happens.  No need to wait for other users to vote. If you see something that needs mod attention just flag it.

Comment: @JamesJenkins just because some mods spend less time here doesn't mean the things they do behind the scenes is not hard. Dealing with chains of comments and figuring out which ones should be kept and which ones should be deleted and which ones should be moved to chat is hard work. Sorting through disagreements between users and deciding on if someone needs a suspension or warning is also hard. Being a mod does not mean you have to spend lots of time asking and answering questions. Being a mod means you are in touch with the community and dealing with issues that require the mod tools.

Comment: @StrongBad I agree that the responsibilities of being a moderator come with some difficult tasks to work through. Some can be unpleasant.   But being a moderator is a volunteer position, you need not do anything you don't want to, but at the same time you have an obligation to the community. If you don't want to do something that needs to be done, ensure someone is available to do it.

Comment: I upvoted this and Strongbad's answers. I appreciate the help, time, and links. This probably comes from being a mod elsewhere and high-rep user here and elsewhere. I always check SE:Meta for procedure questions (I found some related. They're old, I don't know if they're current.) I learn from questions like these at site metas too. I'll take advice in these answers or give it up! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot and I am not sure why you would want to. There are two issues. First, moderators are just regular users with a few more tools. Moderators are not allowed to give you advice (private or otherwise) based on information they learn from those tools. Given that, it is not clear why you would need advice from a moderator as opposed to anyone else familiar with the community.

Second, while sometimes doing things in private might seem like a good thing, it really hampers communication. You sometimes see this after a user is suspended and then starts to give a biased account of what happened. Moderators sometimes chime in, but they never give a full account from their perspective because they respect the privacy of the user. If you go into a private chat room with a mod (or high rep user) and then start repeating things that were said there, we only get one side of the story.

What you can do, and what I suggest you do, is create a public chat room and invite a few experienced users that you respect (by invite, I mean ping them in the regular chat room and tell them about the new room). Then you can ask them for advice. The room won't be private and other people can see and even join the discussion, but most users don't want to join a discussion that they are not invited.

Comment: This is very helpful and I appreciate the time you took to provide it! I upvoted it, and James Jenkins's. It's interesting that you and he are both mods elsewhere and high rep users in many places. I'll take this as advice from both of those positions! I found some related SE:Meta posts which are really old, so I don't know if they're current. People ask procedural questions at their site metas too, and I learn from them. As I told James, I'll take your advice, or give up! Thanks again!!